# Why is my custom class not serializing correctly? Or is it?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, class, serialization

I am attempting to Serialize a Custom Class but it has a List<> of another custom class in it.

The Custom Class is very simple:

```
[Serializable]
public class World
{
    public List<TileData> WorldTiles = new List<TileData>(); //Collection of all tiles.
}
```

This fails to send over the network, without errors, without warnings, without messages. Client just never receives the data.

However, what DOES work is if I do the exact same thing, with only ONE TileData, rather than a List.

```
[Serializable]
public class TileData
{
    public myVector3 myPosition = new myVector3();   //Tile's Transform.Position
    public myVector2 tilePosition = new myVector2(); //Tile's TilePosition
    public string myName; //Name of Prefab to load (What Tile type?)
    public string myBiome; //Biome the Tile belongs to

    public List<ObjectData> myObjects = new List<ObjectData>(); //A list of all the Tile's objects.
}
```

If I send a single "TileData" object over the network, all is well.

If I send a single "World" object over the network, it fails. No errors, client just never receives the data.

**I know your first thought is that the error could lie in the network part, but everything else works perfectly** (all primitives, byte[] I create manually, my custom class "TileData" serialized, but not my custom class "World". That is the only thing that doesn't make it through.)

So I thought I may be serializing this specific class incorrectly?

I used two methods, both do the same thing,

```
// Convert an object to a byte array
public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(System.Object obj)
{
    BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
    return ms.ToArray();
}
```

and

```
// Convert an object to a byte array
  public static byte[] ObjectToByteArray(World obj)
  {
      BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
      using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
          bf.Serialize(ms, obj);
          ms.close();
          return ms.ToArray();
      }
  }
```

Comment: Well everything looks fine for me, only thing I encountered while reading your code is that you don't close the `MemoryStream` in your `ObjectToByteArray` method. Maybe try this and see again?

Comment: I tried closing the stream, and it fails the same.

If the "World" class' List<TileData> WorldTiles is empty (Count = 0) then it works.

I tried sending just the TileData. If the TileData's List<ObjectData> myObjects is populated by more than 3 objects, it fails.

But if serialization looks fine, then it must be the networking that is the problem. I just don't understand why, but I have someone looking into the solution that is much more experienced than me. Thank you.

Comment: Please try to serialize the world object into a local binary file and read it again. Just to be sure the networking is the issue here or not.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: It worked perfectly serializing to file, closing file, opening, then deserializing. Thanks.

Comment: My serialization method was perfectly fine & I did nothing wrong. It took me hours to convince them, but I FINALLY convinced the experienced veteran programmer that it was his problem (his code, his software, not mine). What a headache & waste of my time, since I had to provide tons of evidence & examples that this obvious problem exists. Such enormous problem too & so obvious, but he refused to acknowledge it & claimed his code did what it literally didn't do even for him. Ergh!